# FeildInfo.SetValue(object obj,object value) make no change to field of object

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I've been trying to dynamically assign to structures using reflection to read a file into a struct of named strings, however the process fails to load the assigned values into the structure parameters.
The code below shares the same issue, any insight as to why testints fields are not updated by this process would be appreciated

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
namespace Reflection_Testing
{
    struct testints
    {
        public int t1;
        public int t2;
        public int t3;
        public int t4;
        public int t5;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testints test1 = new testints();
            

            foreach (var feild in test1.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                feild.SetValue(test1, 17);
            }
            foreach (var feild in test1.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("print test 1");

                Console.WriteLine(feild.GetValue(test1));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
print test 1
17
print test 1
17
print test 1
17
print test 1
17
print test 1
17
```

Actual output:

```
print test 1
0
print test 1
0
print test 1
0
print test 1
0
print test 1
0
```

Comment: The struct gets boxed in the SetValue() call, it is the boxed copy that gets updated.  Nothing that you can see back.  Get ahead by declaring it as a class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'd recommend avoiding mutable structs in *almost* all cases. If this were a class, you'd be fine, because there would be no boxing involved.

The problem is that every time you execute this:

```cs
feild.SetValue(test1, 17);
```

you're [*boxing*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) `test1` - creating a new object in memory which is a *copy* of `test1`, and passing a reference to that object to the `SetValue` method. The field will be set on that object - but you no longer have a reference to the object, so you never see it.

If you box *once*, make all the changes to the boxed object, and then either unbox afterwards or just call `GetField` on the boxed object, it will give you the output you expected:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

struct TestInts
{
    public int t1;
    public int t2;
    public int t3;
    public int t4;
    public int t5;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestInts test1 = new TestInts();

        // Box the value once
        object boxed = test1;
        foreach (var field in test1.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            field.SetValue(boxed, 17);
        }

        foreach (var field in test1.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{field.Name}: {field.GetValue(boxed)}");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the value back in your `test1` variable, you need to unbox:

```cs
test1 = (TestInts) boxed;
```

Comment: I'd always seen this issue connected to boxing, never realized it was the call to FeildInfo.Setvalue() itself that was doing the boxing, thank you for clarifying that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired behavior with next code (so it seems declaring `testints` as `class` is more appropriate here, please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) guideline):

```
object test1 = new testints();

foreach (var feild in test1.GetType().GetFields())
{
    feild.SetValue(test1, 17);
}
foreach (var feild in test1.GetType().GetFields())
{
    Console.WriteLine("print test 1");

    Console.WriteLine(feild.GetValue(test1));
}
```

This will [box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) `test1` and pass it to `GetValue`/`SetValue` accepting an `object`. Also take into account that even without boxing `struct`'s are passed by value(a copy is created and passed to method), so the next will also fail without [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) modifier:

```
static void Set(testints t)
{
    t.t1 = 17;
}

var test2 = new testints();
Set(test2);
Console.WriteLine(test2.t1); // prints "0"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail that structs are passed by value, I'd always assumed changes to their fields in called functions/methods would be visible to the caller. This will be a huge help in future projects.

Comment: @DerekStuder was glad to help!